# The association refers to the inverse side field which does not exist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entities:

### TicketEntity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass()
 */
class Ticket implements TicketInterface
{
    const DIR_UPLOAD = 'TicketUpload';

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Attachment", mappedBy="ticket", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $attachments;

    /**
     * Ticket constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->attachments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add attachments
     *
     * @param Attachment $attachments
     * @return Ticket
     */
    public function addAttachment(Attachment $attachments)
    {
        $this->attachments[] = $attachments;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove attachments
     *
     * @param Attachment $attachments
     */
    public function removeAttachment(Attachment $attachments)
    {
        $this->attachments->removeElement($attachments);
    }

    /**
     * Get attachments
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getAttachments()
    {
        return $this->attachments;
    }

}
```

### AttachmentEntity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\AttachmentRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="ticket_attachments")
 */
class Attachment
{
    const DIR_UPLOAD = 'TicketUpload';

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Ticket", inversedBy="attachments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticket_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $ticket;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "300k",
     *     mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf", "text/plain", "application/msword",
     *     "application/vnd.ms-excel", "image/jpeg", "image/x-citrix-jpeg", "image/png", "image/x-citrix-png", "image/x-png", "image/gif"},
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "Liste de formats de fichiers acceptés : .pdf,.txt,.doc,.xls,.jpg,.png,.gif"
     * )
     */
    private $attachmentFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     *
     */
    private $attachment;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


    public function setName($name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTicket(): ?Ticket
    {
        return $this->ticket;
    }

    public function setTicket(Ticket $ticket): void
    {
        $this->ticket = $ticket;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAttachment(): ?string
    {
        return $this->attachment;
    }

    public function setAttachment($attachment): self
    {
        $this->attachment = $attachment;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAttachmentFile(): ?UploadedFile
    {
        return $this->attachmentFile;
    }

    /**
     * @param $attachmentFile
     * @return Ticket
     */
    public function setAttachmentFile($attachmentFile): self
    {
        $this->attachmentFile = $attachmentFile;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getAttachmentWebPath()
    {
        return self::DIR_UPLOAD . '/' . $this->getAttachment();
    }
}
```

My goal is that a ticket can have several attachments.

And I have this error:

> The association AppBundle\Entity\Attachment#ticket refers to the
>   inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\Ticket#attachments which does not
>   exist.

I don't know where I'm wrong... Anyone know ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mapped superclasses are really inconvenient. really. (emphasis mine)](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

> A mapped superclass cannot be an entity, it is not query-able and
>   persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must be
>   unidirectional (with an owning side only). **This means that One-To-Many
>   associations are not possible on a mapped superclass at all.**
>   Furthermore Many-To-Many associations are only possible if the mapped
>   superclass is only used in exactly one entity at the moment. For
>   further support of inheritance, the single or joined table inheritance
>   features have to be used.

so, you're not *technically* doing something wrong, it just isn't supported at all. The error message produced isn't helpful at all though...